# Ubuntu package management (basic): sudo apt-get upgrade firefox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-managers

Just wanted to update firefox from 11.0 to 13.0 on the latest
ubuntu so did the following:

$ sudo apt-get upgrade firefox

thinking that my firefox would be upgraded.

Instead ubuntu started to update every single package in the
whole system it seems. Now I cannot stop the process for fear
that if I do it might leave the system in an inconsistent state.

Where have I gone wrong in issuing the right command for upgrading
a single package in the command line. OK, thankfully 15 minutes
later the command returned successfully.

What is the difference between upgrade and update?

Thanks,

John Goche

Comment: Hi John, your question is not a programming question. Try Superuser in StackExchange.

Comment: Not a programming question, so off-topic for Stack Overflow. [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) would be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 6):

Taken directly from the apt-get man page:

```
update
   update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their
   sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the
   location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list. For example, when
   using a Debian archive, this command retrieves and scans the
   Packages.gz files, so that information about new and updated
   packages is available. An update should always be performed before
   an upgrade or dist-upgrade. Please be aware that the overall
   progress meter will be incorrect as the size of the package files
   cannot be known in advance.

upgrade
   upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
   currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
   /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
   versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
   circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
   not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
   currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
   changing the install status of another package will be left at
   their current version. An update must be performed first so that
   apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.
```

Update is used to update the apt-get package list, upgrade is used to install updates for *all* packages. To update just one package, use install.

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox
```

You must use install command to install and to update package also.

Answer (score 0):

From `man apt-get`:

> upgrade
>
> upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated
>   in
>              /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded
>
> (...)
>
> install
>
> install is followed by one or more packages desired for installation or upgrading.
>
> (...)